# OWL Carousel: Getting index of object that is clicked

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

So I am trying to use the Carousel for navigation on a UI that I am designing, I'm just wondering if there is a way to easily get the index of one of the div objects within the carousel.

I am trying to make it when I click one of the divs, that it centers it within the carousel, so if I can get the index of the div that has been clicked I can then call the code below to set that as the center item.

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel();
owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', NUMBEROFDIVCLICKED);
```

Image of what i'm trying to do:
[image: To-be picture of movement of items]

Comment: I've added a demo that proofs my answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Obviously you speaking about version 2.0 beta because you're using `to.owl.carousel`. I would not go with the solution from Leif because it won't work in many cases. So this is what you can do:

```
$('.owl-carousel').on('click', '.owl-item', function(e) {
  var carousel = $('.owl-carousel').data('owl.carousel');
  e.preventDefault();
  carousel.to(carousel.relative($(this).index()));
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/caqayopi/1). But please notice it's beta and might change. You have also to use the latest [development](https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel2/archive/develop.zip).

Depend on what plugins your are using (navigation) you have to write the `to` call like this:

```
carousel.to(carousel.relative($(this).index()), false, true);
```

Here are some explanations:

- `$(this).index()` is part of jQuery and gives you the position of the clicked item `.owl-item` within its container.
- `$('.owl-carousel').data('owl.carousel')` gives you the plugin object of Owl Carousel, thus you can use the API directly without using the plugin method (`$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel('method', 'arg')`) or jQuery events (`$('.owl-carousel').trigger('method', ['arg'])`).
- `carousel.relative($(this).index())` gives you the relative position of the clicked item. This is always necessary when you have `loop` activated, which uses cloned items and thus you have more items before you started the plugin.
- `carousel.to()` only accepts relative positions.

Comment: I'm using 2.0.0-beta.2.4 and data "owl.carousel" does not exist anymore, i found owlCarousel but the result of clicking an item is... strange... It seems that is a bug of this version...  to(0) puts first item in first position, to(1) puts second item in third position... to(2) puts third item in third position to (same result as t(0))

Comment: I used e.page.index, gives the relative index like clones did not exist

Comment: @witrin thank you for this, I was using the 'to.owl.carousel' trigger with loop enabled and banging my head against a wall! Works perfectly now.

Comment: its working,.. well why this owl.carousel things don't have their own on click listener

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a much cleaner solution using owl.events.

First, wire up an event to your owl configuration.

*Note there are a list of other events you can listen for as well here: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html*

**Example:**

```
var owl, numberOfSlides, slideIndexBeforeChange;


owl = $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            onInitialized: counter, //When the plugin has initialized.
            onTranslate : counter, //When the translation of the stage has started.
}
```

Then Create your function to capture the event and it's properties

```
function counter(event) {
            numberOfSlides = event.item.count;     // Number of items
            slideIndexBeforeChange = event.item.index;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the owl.goTo event. This will however scroll the supplied item all to the left.
For example: If you show 5 items, like in your screenshot, you have to use index - 2:

```
owl.find('.owl-wrapper').on('click', '.owl-item', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    owl.trigger('owl.goTo', $(this).index() - 2) 
});
```

Read "4. Custom Events" at http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#customizing for more details on the events.